# What does prefix to MoveNext mean in the stackstace?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, crash, windbg

The .NET application crashes with the stack trace:

Call Stack:

```
Layouts!Layouts.Ribbon.SizeAndPositionControlViewModel+OnLayoutSelectionChanged>d__5.MoveNext() 
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(System.Object)
WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
```

The rest of the callstack is Windows code and does not matter.

Here's what the first call implies:
In the async method `OnLayoutSelectionChanged()` in the instance of `SizeAndPositionControlViewModel` it failed in method `MoveNext()`. `MoveNext()` happens to be Microsoft code in a LINQ method method `Any`.

What does d__5 signify ?

Comment: Linq creates temporary `IEnumerable` classes that evaluate the results.  `d__5.MoveNext` is an iteration over the `IEnumerable` it created.

Answer (score 21):

The `d__5` portion is a prefix that is generated by the C# compiler to keep the construct unique from other generated members / types.   In this case the `d` prefix means that it is an iterator or async method generated class (`d` is used for both).  The number is just incremented for every name that is generated

Answer (score 0):

These are the names of lambda expressions which where auto-generated by the compiler (also anonymous methods may look similar when debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Several of the newer ways of creating returning IEnumerable objects are implemented in the compiler by defining and instantiating "anonymous" classes.  The classes are actually required to have a name, so the compiler generates one like you are seeing.  See e.g. [this article](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/) for what is going on behind the scenes.